# Moving the cursor using the touchpad inserts "C"

Tags: macos, trackpad

This problem happens when I use Parallels (Windows) and Beyond Compare.
When I move the mouse using the touchpad, it will automatically insert <kbd>C</kbd> in any place that can input characters.

My OS X is 10.10.5.

[image]

**Update 2015-12-29**
I find when I move the cursor, the `Edit` will shines, also I imagine <kbd>C</kbd> related to copy.
[image]

Comment: You maybe consider GIFing the problem?

Comment: @nicael Excuse me, what's meaning of GIFing?

Comment: Please take a GIF of your problem.

Comment: Do you have any apps running in the background that could be responsible for this behaviour? This is very irregular but apps like Autopairs can modify the usual keyboard input.

Comment: @Konrad How can I know which program I run in background? I type `htop` but can't have any idea.

Comment: Hey, that's pretty cool. How'd you make that .gif?

Comment: @tjt263 I use quicktime to capture the screen and saves into MOV. And then use ffmpeg `ffmpeg -ss 0  -i C-problem.mov -t 30 -pix_fmt rgb24 -r 10 -f gif - | gifsicle --optimize=3 --delay=3 > C_problem.gif`

Answer (score 1):

After three months, I finally found reason. The `Eudic` I installed has function called `Zoned word translation`. When I open this function, the program will automatically copy text when I use mouse to select it. That will be fine in OS X. But in some application like parallel, it will show this problem.

Solution: cancel this function in the `Eudic` program setting.